# Insert mass streaming data in mysql using C#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, multithreading, insert

I use Mysql and I need to insert mass data. The data is streamed to my server in the form of a list of 5k rows. I need to insert more than 3k requests, that means 3k request * 5k rows = 15 000 000 rows.

What I did was used create threads and insert using those threads, as the data come in packets of 5k in an async event. The data response is generated on my request.

What is the best possible way to do it, keeping this scenario in mind?

ThreadPooling for thread managment or simple multithreaded applition and will threads benifit in insertion as I need to insert in a single table (Innodb engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache incoming requests on a server. Keep some buffered data in-memory until you get *N* requests (which you can fine-tune later). Once you get those you just flush data into MySql using some bulk insert routine. It is generally much faster to do one big insert than many small ones.

You can use [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) class to keep data on the server. This is a thread-safe collection.

Additionally, you may need to expire cache based on time. This will cover the case where you get some requests *n < N* and then a client just stops sending data. You would want to flush it anyways and not wait forever until next upcoming requests fully fill the cache.

Comment: Some bulk insert is not very specific.  Still +1 for ConcurrentBag.

Comment: It is *some bulk insert* because OP didn't specify what he uses for the data layer communication: ORM, .NET MySql Data Provider (or driver as it may be refered to), SQL or something else. I gave him a hint to search for the *bulk* insert. Tnx for +1 though.

Comment: One moret thing,
The response I get from the server is in a async response.
So I want to know that the async response is it self a thread or it is on the main UI thread? 
And again, if it not a different thread, does creating threads on the response will increase the insertion ?
Thanks in advance